# How to make requests in react correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am new to ReactJS and I'm trying to create field where I can write down a city name and get it's current weather.

### Here's the code I have

```
const key = '&APPID=fe338dab6a1fd5b27b01a15c12a16391'
const URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=';
class Index extends React.Component {
constructor(prop) {
    super(prop);

    this.state = {
        city: '',
        data: [],
        isLoaded: false
    }
}

getWeather(city) {
    fetch(URL + city + key)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
}

updateCity(e) {
    this.setState({city: e.target.value});
}


render() {
    let city = this.state.city;
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="city" onChange={this.updateCity.bind(this)} />
            <button onClick={this.getWeather(city)}>touch me soy boy</button>
        </div>
    );
}

}
export default Index;`
```

My problem is that it sends requests every time I write a symbol. 
How to make it send request only when I press the button?

Also, recommend me any sources where I can learn more about React to stop asking questions on this site =)

Comment: @vsync that is incorrect

Comment: I don't think you should pass `city` at all in the `render` method to the `getWeather` but rather `getWeather` should get the city directly from the state, so write it as I've said before `updateCity =(e) => {` so you could access the `this.state` properly within it

Comment: @epascarello - I just haven't explained myself fully. read my updated comment above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want to pass city when you are maintaining it in state.

```
<button onClick={this.getWeather}>Get Weather</button>
```

And in your getWeather function get the city 
const {city} = this.state;

Answer (score 3):

Just Syntax:

```
<button onClick={() => this.getWeather(city)}>touch me soy boy</button>
```